# Converting column type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, types, sqldatatypes

I had to bring in a whole bunch of tables from CSV files.  A lot of these files had column that were INT but had null values.  To speed up the import I just made all of the column VARCHAR.  Now I have all this data in the tables but need to change the type.  I'm able to do this in the MySQL workbench except for one problem -- It error's because of the null/blank values.  Is there some sort of SQL magic that will allow me to convert these column types and ignore the nulls or replace them with the correct 'null value' for that data type?

Comment: What do you mean by correct null value?

Comment: Well I mean null overall.  I put it that way because I didn't know if varchar's null is 'null' while int's might be \0  -- I really just mean null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the columns to set blank fields as NULL as follows:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn=NULL WHERE TRIM(mycolumn,' ')='';
```

Then do your normal table alters as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycolumn VARCHAR(255);
```

The 'DEFAULT NULL' is optional as fields by default allow null. This should allow you to convert the columns to whatever data types you wish without any problem except in the case where there is mixed data -- such as numbers, and strings, and you wish to make that column FLOAT.

The above example also does not take into account removing carriage returns, etc, in the event that a column contains a "\n" or "\r\n" and nothing else, it will not set it to NULL, but you can modify the "TRIM(mycolumn, ' ')"  to meet those requirements if you have them :  aka ...

```
UPDATE mytable SET mycolumn=NULL WHERE TRIM(mycolumn,"\n")='';
```

Comment: Thanks, the exact query I used was UPDATE table SET column = NULL WHERE column = '';

Comment: So it was definitely pre-trimmed blanks.  Thats awesome.  I gave the TRIM()'d version as that helps to cover when there are other stray chars in the column that may prevent the search from nulling, but you wish to keep other data in the same column

Comment: Instead of doing this column by column, is there a way to do a oneshot for all columsn to replace '' with NULL?  (I'm not really a SQL guy :) )

Comment: I am not sure. Not without an interpreter in between, or using a stored procedure to loop through the columns.  The methods I am aware using straight SQL would update all columns to blank. Also, you will need to ALTER table after anyway, so I don't think there is a way (that I know at least) to completely automate this. What front-end language are you using ?  (PHP / ASP / etc)

Comment: I'm just doing this from the MySQL command line.  The end project is using Java.

Comment: I am checking to see if I can whip up something cool. Perhaps loop through the columns and output concatenated strings.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to see if I can't do something in Java to speed up the process too.

Comment: Best I can come up with to help you list, would be to use `DESCRIBE mytable;` .  For some reason, MySQL isn't letting me do a `SELECT` statement on that, so I can't loop through the columns for you.  I will keep trying for a bit more.

Comment: In Java, should be a simple matter to open a MySQL connection, and loop through `DESCRIBE mytable` results (the field name is stored in the `Field` column), then just do whatever command to replace the string in the queries above :)